# where is the location of class Normal in edward's source code?

Tags: tensorflow, edward

When using edward, we always use `from edward.models import Normal` , but i didn't find the declaration of `Normal` in [github](https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/tree/master/edward/models)

anybody who can tell me where is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are defined in [`edward/models/random_variables.py`](https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/blob/ec44461ecc7887d3dedf1cd4f1c821bab912b194/edward/models/random_variables.py).

You import the `Normal` class like this:

```
from edward.models import Normal
```

This suggests looking in [`edward/models/__init__.py`](https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/blob/ec44461ecc7887d3dedf1cd4f1c821bab912b194/edward/models/__init__.py), which has this line:

```
from edward.models.random_variables import *
```

Looking in `edward/models/random_variables.py` we find [this code](https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/blob/ec44461ecc7887d3dedf1cd4f1c821bab912b194/edward/models/random_variables.py#L7-L27):

```
from edward.models.random_variable import RandomVariable as _RandomVariable
from tensorflow.contrib import distributions as _distributions

# Automatically generate random variable classes from classes in
# tf.contrib.distributions.
_globals = globals()
for _name in sorted(dir(_distributions)):
  _candidate = getattr(_distributions, _name)
  if (_inspect.isclass(_candidate) and
          _candidate != _distributions.Distribution and
          issubclass(_candidate, _distributions.Distribution)):

    # to use _candidate's docstring, must write a new __init__ method
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      _RandomVariable.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    __init__.__doc__ = _candidate.__init__.__doc__
    _params = {'__doc__': _candidate.__doc__,
               '__init__': __init__}
    _globals[_name] = type(_name, (_RandomVariable, _candidate), _params)

del _candidate
```

This goes through the `tensorflow.contrib.distributions` module looking for classes derived from `tensorflow.contrib.distributions.Distribution` (ignoring other attributes like e.g. the `__file__` member of the module, or the base `Distribution` class itself). For each one, it does a bit of hacking (which only affects the generated documentation) then executes this key line:

```
_globals[_name] = type(_name, (_RandomVariable, _candidate), _params)
```

The [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#type) built-in function creates a new type i.e. declares a new class. The second parameter is the list of base classes, which here is edward's `RandomVariable` class and the TensorFlow random variable class. Earlier it defined `_globals` to be [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#globals), which is a built-in function returning the dictionary of the module's variables. Therefore, in the case you're interested in, the line above is equivalent to the following:

```
from edward.models.random_variable import RandomVariable as EdRandVar
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import Normal as TfNormal
Normal = type("Normal", (EdRandVar, TfNormal), {...})
```

Which in turn is equivalent to this (if you ignore the docstring stuff):

```
from edward.models.random_variable import RandomVariable as EdRandVar
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import Normal as TfNormal
class Normal(EdRandVar, TfNormal):
    pass
```